# Koalas is incompatible with Sklearn - ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'x'

Tags: python, pandas, databricks, spark-koalas

I try to adapt to [Koalas](https://github.com/databricks/koalas) the code that runs well with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from databricks import koalas as ks
from sklearn import preprocessing

pdf = pd.DataFrame({'x':range(3), 'y':[1,2,5], 'z':[100,200,1000]})

df = ks.from_pandas(pdf)

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
result = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df)
```

It fails at the last line with the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'x'
```

It seems that the header line in Koalas is interpreted as a normal row by `fit_transform` function.

Is there any workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: It works if you transform the `df` to a numpy array. By adding this after creating your `df`: `df = df.to_numpy()`

Comment: @prp: Cool, thanks. But is it possible to use sklearn without transforming Koalas df to Numpy array? I think that the whole idea of Koalas is to benefit from Pandas structures, while handling larger data volumes. If I transform to Numpy, then I loose this benefit.

Answer (score 1):

You will get a little bit further with changing

```
df = ks.from_pandas(pdf)
```

to

```
df = ks.from_pandas(pdf).set_index('x')
```

to explicitly make `x` the index column in the pandas and koalas dataframes.